# GWT - run command exactly once per event loop

Tags: gwt

I'm writing some wrapper classes around zurb foundation.
Foundation widgets need an `init()` function to be called after the elements have been added to the DOM.

I can accomplish this easily enough with this method:

```
public static void initWidgets() {
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            foundationInit();
        }
    });
}
```

...where `foundationInit()` is a JSNI call to the foundation `init()` function. I then add a call to `initWidgets()` in the constructor of any foundation element. So far so good.

However, if multiple foundation widgets are added to the DOM during a particular event loop, then the `init()` method will be called multiple times. Foundation doesn't actually care about this, but it would be nice to find a way around this.

Is there any scheduler functionality / pattern that'd allow me to schedule a particular command to run only once, no matter how many times the schedule method is called with that command?

Something like: `scheduleDeferredIfNotAlreadyScheduled(Command c)`

I don't know how to get a handle on the event loop, so I don't know how to reset a flag that'd tell me whether or not to add the command or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any Scheduller command to do that, but it could be done with a static boolean variable, e.g.:

```
private static boolean initialized;

public static void initWidgets() {
    initialized = false;

    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            if (!initialized) {
                initialized = true;
                foundationInit();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However that doesn't work if another foundation element is inserted without a full page refresh. I.e. the "initialized" flag is going to be turned off and never run again. foundationInit() has to be run every time I insert elements into the dom.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. I think I do now. See my modified answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the edit. Initialized will never be toggled back to false as the code currently stands.

Comment: Yes, I moved the `initialized = false;` inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

In such case I usually use Guava's Supplier.double checked locking  is really safe.

```
public static Supplier<Boolean> supplier=Suppliers.memoize(new Supplier<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean get() {
        foundationInit();
        return true;
    }
});

public static void initWidgets() {
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            boolean initialized=supplier.get();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's a nice pattern, however like @David Levesque's answer it isn't sensitive to the event loop. If during the next event loop a foundation widget is inserted, the init function should be run again.